Vue: Sending an Array of Objects, with each Object has a Multipart File Arrays
i have a problem in my Vue project.
I need to send an array of objects to the backend. Each object contains a property that is an array of MultipartFile.
I've tried(files is an array attribute of component, added new element when input a file):
submitExamFile: function () {
                let formData = new FormData();

                this.files .forEach((e, index) => {
                    formData.append(`files[${index}].file`, JSON.stringify(e.file));
                    formData.append(`files[${index}].loginName`, "defaultLoginName"); 
                });

                 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.$api
                        .post("/save", params)
                        .then((response) => {
                            resolve(Number(response.data));
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            reject(err.response);
                        });
                });
            },

And at the backend, I receive the data in the following Controller format:
@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    public JsonResponse save(@RequestParam("files ") List<Vo> files ,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        int rowEffected = service.save(files);
        return new JsonResponse().success(rowEffected);
    }

My Value Object Class (java)

public class Vo {
private String isRemoved;
private MultipartFile[] examFile;
}
//constructor, getter, setter...

I need a solution for this

Why JSON.stringify the file ?! also it seems like you are defining the formData but not using it, can you share the exact error please?
